# HAPI FHIR OpenAPI Authentication Configuration

Tags: openapi, hapi, hapi-fhir

Hi standing up a small FHIR v4 server with HAPI.  I'm not great with Spring/Java having a hard time figuring out how to configure openapi with HAPI FHIR.  Specifically I want to configure openapi to provide a button to authenticate users (with an implicit flow against my IDP) before allowing them to hit my FHIR endpoints.  Does the built in HAPI OpenApiInterceptor have a way to provide an authentication mechinism?

https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/openapi.html

To clarify I can add the interceptor and get the swagger page to get served but I cannot figure out how to configure the interceptor such that I can provide a mechinism to authenticate users.  This code block works but doesn't appear to provide me a way to configure swagger auth.

```
   @Override
   protected void initialize() throws ServletException {

      // ... define your resource providers here ...

      // Now register the interceptor
      OpenApiInterceptor openApiInterceptor = new OpenApiInterceptor();
      registerInterceptor(openApiInterceptor);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **extend** the **OpenApiInterceptor** class and **@Override** the "**generateOpenApi**" method to add your extra needed OpenAPI configuration **after calling the parent method**.

```
public class CustomOpenApiInterceptor extends OpenApiInterceptor {

...

@Override
protected OpenAPI generateOpenApi(ServletRequestDetails theRequestDetails) {
    OpenAPI openApi = super.generateOpenApi(theRequestDetails);
    // Add Authentication to OAS spec.
    openApi.getComponents().addSecuritySchemes("oauth2schema", oauth2ImplicitSecurityScheme());
    SecurityRequirement securityRequirement = new SecurityRequirement();
    securityRequirement.addList("oauth2schema");
    openApi.security(Collections.singletonList(securityRequirement));
    return openApi;
}

...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OpenApiInterceptor does not performs authorization of users.
Hapi has provided us various interceptors to perform some tasks
in your case you should refer this, it will give you some idea.

[Hapi fhir authorization interceptor](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/security/authorization_interceptor.html)